# can I exclude a slack @channel messages from "unread messages" indicator

Tags: slack

I'm using slack app on windows and the icon in the notification area shows a red dot to indicate when there are new messages which I find very useful.

Unfortunately one of my workspaces has a channel where a lot of people like to post messages using "@channel". I have tried to leave the channel but it says "Every workspace has one channel that contains all the members of this workspace – this is that channel for you". It's a customer I rarely work with but I can't completely remove their slack workspace from my app in case they do need to contact me.

I have turned off notifications which works fine but what I'd really like is to have it not flag the red dot when there are notifications in this specific channel (or alternatively turn off the red dot for all @channel notifications)